# Are we able to generate a list of loaded packages in R?

Tags: r, namespaces, package, loaded, search-path

Is there a function where we can generate a list of required packages in R? Something similar to "pip freeze" so we can duplicate environments quickly?

Comment: Do you mean `search()`?

Comment: `sessionInfo()` might be of interest

Comment: Did you mean generating that list a) after running the specific code in R interpreter or b) statically analyze the code without running it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for not being vague.  Since you mentioned duplicating environments, here's some info about availability and namespaces of those available packages.

In addition to those functions mentioned by @smci, `.Packages` will list all packages available in the library location path `lib.loc`. And `find.package` will show you the path to the package.  Bear in mind that `find.packages` can present issues when determining availability of a package.  `require` is the recommended method (see `?find.package` for explanation).

```
> x <- .packages(TRUE)
> head(x)
# [1] "assertthat"      "BH"              "car"             "data.table"     
# [5] "digest"          "dplyr"
> f <- find.package(x)
> sample(f, 5)
# [1] "/home/richard/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/latticeExtra"  
# [2] "/home/richard/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Lahman"        
# [3] "/home/richard/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/microbenchmark"
# [4] "/usr/lib/R/library/tools"                                      
# [5] "/home/richard/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/knitr"
```

For a list of the environments with namespaces for those packages in `x`, you can use (among others) `getNamespace`

```
> sapply(x, getNamespace)[1:3]
# $assertthat
# <environment: namespace:assertthat>

# $BH
# <environment: namespace:BH>

# $car
# <environment: namespace:car>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you meant "***after running the code in question***":

- `loadedNamespaces()` (for just the package names, or)
- `search()` as @Richard Scriven said

but if you meant ***statically analyze the code in question without running it***, there's no tool I'm aware of, but mungeing the output of `egrep -R -w '(require|include|source)' *.r` should give you what you want (obviously will also pick up packages included but not used, or commented out)