# How to determine what R packages were actually used (not just loaded)

Tags: r, citations

[How do I tell which R packages to cite in my paper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535628/how-do-i-tell-which-r-packages-to-cite-in-my-paper/27535629#) discusses the use of sessionInfo() to find and cite loaded packages. Is there a sensible way to list which packages have been used (not just loaded)?

Comment: You should have scripts saved for your analyses. What packages do you need load for them to run without error? You might consider using something like packrat to manage this for you.

Comment: Start R with `--vanilla`. Run your code. Literally _everything_ that's in (I use `devtools`) `devtools::session_info()` afterwards was instrumental in ensuring you were able to do your paper-worthy analysis. So they should all be cited. We devoted real space to this in our book http://stackoverflow.com/a/23528042/1457051 (so it's not just a pontification)

Comment: Here you will find a good shell command using `grep` to extract all used packages from your source code:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23439356/4468078